# Why can't I override `to_dict` method of a `dataclass` object that uses `dataclasses_json`?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

[dataclasses_json](https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/) is a library that provides JSON capabilities to python's data classes. I noticed that overriding `to_dict` method has no effect. Here's an example:

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Message2:
    message: str
    weight: int
    def to_dict(self, encode_json=False):
        print('Custom to_dict')
        ret = {'MESSAGE': self.message, 'WEIGHT': self.weight}
        return ret
m2 = Message2('m2', 2)
print(m2.to_dict())
```

The code prints the following:

{'message': 'm2', 'weight': 2}

While I was expecting

```
Custom to_dict
{'MESSAGE': 'm2', 'WEIGHT': 2}
```

If I remove the `@dataclass_json` line, I get the desired output.

So, my questions are:

1. Why defining a function had no effect with `@dataclass_json` but worked without it?
2. How can I override `to_dict` and use `@dataclass_json`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Because `dataclass_json` simply overrides your `to_dict` method [here](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json/blob/master/dataclasses_json/api.py#L213):

```
    cls.to_dict = DataClassJsonMixin.to_dict
```

2. One possible way is to define a method with different name and after applying `dataclass_json` decorator use this method to create `to_dict` method. Complete example with decorator:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


def recover_to_dict(cls):
    if hasattr(cls, '_to_dict'):
        setattr(cls, 'to_dict', getattr(cls, '_to_dict'))
    return cls


@recover_to_dict
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Message2:
    message: str
    weight: int
    def _to_dict(self, encode_json=False):
        print('Custom to_dict')
        ret = {'MESSAGE': self.message, 'WEIGHT': self.weight}
        return ret
m2 = Message2('m2', 2)
print(m2.to_dict())
```

Comment: Oh, so my mental model was that "my" code happens after the decorator code. But it actually makes sense that the decorator **decorates** my code ...