# dataclass_json : get class name inside the json/dict object

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses

I am using the library [`dataclass_json`](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json) in python and I was wondering whether there is a way to return the class name inside the dict/json.

Here is an example of what I would like to obtain:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str

person = Person(name='lidatong')

# What I would like to obtain

person.to_json()  # '{ "Person": {"name": "lidatong"} }'
person.to_dict()  # { 'Person': {'name': 'lidatong'} }

# instead of the current behavior

person.to_json()  # '{"name": "lidatong"}'
person.to_dict()  # {'name': 'lidatong'}
```

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: That's not how serialization is expected to work. Can you do it by wrapping the call ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that serialization does not work this way.I just need this kind of format for a specific software input. I try your suggestion, to wrap the function `to_dict` call but it does not seem to work or I do it the wrong way. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884043/17925831

Answer (score 0):

JSON serialization comes from Javascript, which is not class-based but prototype-based, so it usually omit the class name (because it does not matter much to the code). But the name can matter to humans, so I understand your need.

If you can control how the code is called, then you can create a simple function :

```py
import json

def to_my_custom_json(person: Person) -> str:
    return json.dumps({"Person": person.to_dict()})
```

which gives you exactly what you wanted :

```py
print(to_my_custom_json(person))  # {"Person": {"name": "lidatong"}}
```

It can also be added to the class itself :

```py
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str

    def to_my_custom_json(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps({"Person": self.to_dict()})

print(person.to_my_custom_json())  # {"Person": {"name": "lidatong"}}
```

But if can't control how your object gets serialized (typically in a framework), then you omitted to specify it in your question.